# How to use python 'in' operator with generator class queryset results in function?

Tags: python, django, iterator

I need to check if a <class 'str'> value exists in a list generated by queryset.
Now, this works perfectly when used in a view.

```
my_string = 'Granny Smith'
my_query = Orchard.objects.all().values_list('apples', flat=True).iterator()
if my_string in my_query:
    print('This works ok', type(my_string), type(my_query))
    # Print: 'This works ok, <class 'str'>, <class 'generator'>
```

The problem occurs, when I try to pass queryset results as a parameter in a function:

```
def my_function(queryset_data):
    other_string = 'Granny Smith'
    if other_string in queryset_data:
       print('There is Belle de Boskoop in my q results.', type(other_string), type(queryset_data))
```

Am I passing the queryset results from the view correctly or are class generator values not meant to be used this way?

The reason why I am using iterator(): I need a lightning-fast, cache-less query, every delay hurts my app. By using iterator(), there is no repeated query or caching as stated in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if there is any record with matching string then you can just use:

```
my_string = 'Granny Smith'

# query of all Orchard record with apples='Granny Smith'
my_query = Orchard.objects.filter(apples=my_string)

# check if any record exists. Returns boolean
is_record_found = my_query.exists()
```

Comment: this is good way to find if a record exists, but I do not wish to perform any additional queries (even though .exists() is among the simplest queries), and can only work with already fetched data. Additionally, my goal is to use iterator() which further promotes the idea of using only one query and working with its results.

Comment: You can just do the first query (the one with the filter) and then use `if my_query`. This way there will be only one query made even if you need to pull some data from the objects

Comment: I have no issue with checking if query exists or if data is fetched. As a matter of fact, the original view works without a problem. Problem occurs, when query's data (shaped by iterator()) is being passed to a function and then the same operation with 'in' being executed. Main cause of the problem, is in the function.